# undefined method `stock_delta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff2ecae9c28>:0x007ff2ef823248>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, path, routes

I'm new to Rails and following the starting guide since what I want to do makes use of nested classes anyway. I keep getting thing error:

```
undefined method `stock_delta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff2ecae9c28>:0x007ff2ef823248>
```

It's occuring on my view at this line here:

```
<%= form_for([@stock, @stock.deltas.build]) do |f| %>
```

Instead of having Articles and Comments like the normal tutorial I'm using Stocks and Deltas respectively. I added this to routes:

```
resources :stocks do
  resources :deltas
end
```

Any idea what this issue is? I've gone through any other stack overflow examples I can find and nothing seems to work, I've also used the guide very carefully trying to find any pluralization issues I might have to no adue, any suggestions?

EDIT: Delta controller below:

```
class DeltasController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @stock = find_stock
        @delta = @stock.deltas.build
    end

    def create 
        @stock = find_stock
        @delta = @stock.deltas.create(delta_params)
        redirect_to stock_path(@stock)
    end

    private
        def delta_params
            params.require(:delta).permit(:start, :length)
        end

        def find_stock
      return Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    end
end
```

Second edit, view code added:

```
<h1> Stock </h1>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Hashtag</th>        
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= @stock.name %></td>
            <td><%= @stock.hashtag %></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<h2>Deltas: </h2>
  <table> 
    <tr>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Hashtag</th>    
    </tr>
    <% @stock.deltas.each do |delta| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @delta.start %></td>
        <td><%= @delta.length %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<h2>Add a Delta:</h2>
<%= form_for([@stock, @stock.deltas.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :length %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :length %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', stocks_path%>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stock_path(@stock)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do this

```
def new
  /////do whatever you want here and get the stock
  @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
  ////build the deltas here 
  @delta = @stock.deltas.build
end
```

and in your view try this

```
<%= form_for [@stock, @delta] do |f| %>
```

Comment: I did these changes and got this error message instead: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: have you find @stock on your controller ? it should be blank that's why it is giving you this error

Comment: Added the delta controller to the OP

Comment: please check @stock having value or not ?

Comment: you need to pass params[:stock_id] to deltascontroller from where you are calling your new delta, in order to find the Stock and after that build the deltas and then use in your form_for helper.

Comment: Isn't that being done by passing the @stock in the form for.. this line here: <%= form_for([@stock, @stock.deltas.build]) do |f| %> ?

Comment: you are getting this error because your @stock is nil. so it should have the value otherwise it show the same error that you are getting.

Comment: So it's just not properly finding a stock ?

Comment: What could I do to remedy this ?

Comment: In this line here? <%= form_for([@stock, @delta]) do |f| %>   <p>
Where would I pass it in?